# I Want A Post Request Function In JS & HTML Like My Python Code

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, request

I am trying to make a html page. I am good at Python but not good at JS.
I have A Python code but I want a code in JS like that.
Anyone help me :)

Here My Python Code:

```
import requests

post_url = "MY_REQUEST_URL"
data = {"data1": "A_DATA_FROM_USER", "data2": "MY_DATA"}

response = requests.post(post_url, data=data)
result = response.headers["MY_HEADER_NAME"]
```

Here My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My Heading</h2>

My Input: <input type="text" id="userdata" name="url" value="A_DATA_FROM_USER"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="A_FUNCTION"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
THIS SCRIPT I WANT
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a JS Script to get input from user using HTML And Display output in HTML.

result(in python code) will be display in output element(in html code)

userdata = A_DATA_FROM_USER (input from user)

Please Use MY_REQUEST_URL, A_DATA_FROM_USER, MY_DATA, MY_HEADER_NAME in JS

Answer (score 0):

To make a post call you can use pure javascript (fetch function), but usually websites use jquery library that allow you to use AJAX.
Ajax comes with function that allow you to make a simple post request by using $.ajax() function.

You can use jquery via cdn so you don't have to download that.
So, before your custom  add the include and then the script. Like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
Custom script
</script>
```

In pure javascript, to interact with the HTML elements you have to use

document.querySelector() or document.getElementById().

For example to put a string inside your output div you should to this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Result that shows inside the div";
```

If you use jquery instead, you can use it to interact with the dom (jquery has a lot of tools, not just AJAX used for HTTP requests).

For example:

```
$("#output").html("Result that shows inside the div");
```

The syntax for the $.ajax is easy, here the working code you are trying to build, add this inside your empty `<script> </script>` tags

```
$.post( 
    "mydomain.com/my-python-page", 
    { 
      userdata: $("#userdata").val() //Gets the userdata input value
    }
  )
  .done(function(data, textStatus, request) { //Request success
    let stringToShow = request.getResponseHeader('the-header-value-you-want-to-take');
    $("#output").html(stringToShow); //Shows the screen in div with id="output"
  })
  .fail(function() { //Request fails
    console.log("Error!");
  });
}
```

Now change `mydomain.com/my-python-page` `the-header-value-you-want-to-take` with the response header value you want to show in output div.

Obviously you have to put it inside the function you write in `onClick="function_name()"`